# Automatically download missing artifacts if missing in Artifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory

I'm using Jfrog Artifactory to contain artifacts. I'm building with Maven. Is there a way to configure Maven to automatically download missing artifacts, artifacts that are not in the Artifactory repo.

Example: 
org.maven.framework-2.5.0 is downloaded from Artifactory since it exists in the Artifactory.
org.maven.anotherframework-2.2.2 doesn't exists in Artifacotry. How to set maven to get from internet?


Is it common to use Artifactory this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should configure Artifactory to fetch missing artifacts from the Internet, not Maven.
Artifactory can (and should) be used as a proxy:

[image]

It already comes with set a pre-configured popular remote repositories and you can add new ones.

So, if Maven fails on unresolved dependency, find a repository that has it, [add it to Artifactory as remote repository](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories), retry the build. If you can't find any repository that has it, you can [upload the jar directly to Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Deploying+via+the+Web+UI) and retry the build.

Comment: thanks. Uploading the jar directly to Artifactory was no problem. However when I'm trying to add remote repository according to the link you provided I was unsure about repository url so I tried this: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ but I got connection timed out. I would like to use maven remote repositories since I can manually download them from there.

Comment: Repo1 should be preconfigured in Artifactory, so you don't need to configure it again. If Artifactory can't reach it, check the network connection out define a proxy (if you need one) in Artifactory settings.

Comment: Repo1 was indeed preconfigured. Tested the repo1 connection and successfully connected to server. However when building, I got: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.4.1 in http://11.222.33.444:8070/artifactory/remote-repos was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of remote-repos has elapsed or updates are forced

Comment: You need to run a trace query to check why Artifactory can't find the plugin in central. That's a whole different story (new question or find an old one, there are bunch of them).

Comment: great @JBaruch. was looking for this link jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories :) But is there a way that Artifactory adds this missing artifact to the "pre-configured" jars, instead of manually adding it?

Comment: what "adding missing artifact to "pre-configured" jars means? I understand all the words, but...